# How to express table highlighting mathematically

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm a computer scientist and recently faced the following problem, and would like to be able to express it mathematically, hopefully in terms of groups/sets/vector spaces (I'm not too sure here)

A table of arbitrary data can have highlighted cells and an option is available to show only rows with highlights. What is the smallest set of functions we can expose that would allow developers to highlight any subset of cells with as few calls as possible. To make things *user friendly* each function can only operate on a column or a row.

The solution evolved as follows:

- First there was a single function that highlighted all cells in a column satisfying a regex.

This was a great start but developers wanted to highlight cells in rows that only had multiple highlights to produce a table that showed more succinct info.

To solve this, we implemented the following function:

- Clear all highlights in a row if there are less than a given threshold of highlights.

This let them highlight the union of interesting values in columns A and B, then remove the symmetric difference by clearing rows with fewer than 2 highlights. This left the intersection they were after, preventing partially matching rows from showing in the highlights only view.

I have a hunch that this set of 2 functions is enough to show any desired subset of a table but I would like to prove it. I'm hoping that in the process I might find a better set of functions.

Comment: Suppose there is a lone highlighted cell in a row, but one with critical data. And there are other single cell rows with non-critical data. They want to keep the critical lone cell row, but hide the rows with non-critical data. You are chasing a chimera by trying to satisfy every possible need. The only way to do that is to provide a macro capability where developers can write their own methods for hiding or showing rows.

Comment: They could apply the critical highlight last. Can't give them arbitrary control (political and technical reasons). I'm really just interested in explaining this mathematically. I feel like this could be described as a group in some way.